# Creating binary identifiers, based on condition of word combinations, for filtering in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi all I wish to know if this is possible. I am still exploring.

For example, I had this data set

```
Case     Date           Item
1        2016-03-25     Alpha
2        2016-03-25     Bravo
3        2016-03-25     Charlie
4        2016-03-25     Delta
5        2016-03-31     Alpha
6        2016-03-31     Echo
7        2016-03-31     Falcon
```

Note that Alpha appears twice in the data set. The thing is, I want to only flag out Alpha and Bravo only, according to the Date. NOTE: Alpha and Bravo, not Alpha alone only.

To illustrate this further, I have this particular code:

```
data %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(combiflag=grepl("Alpha|Bravo", Item))
```

which gives

```
Case     Date           Item        combiflag
1        2016-03-25     Alpha       TRUE
2        2016-03-25     Bravo       TRUE
3        2016-03-25     Charlie     FALSE
4        2016-03-25     Delta       FALSE
5        2016-03-31     Alpha       TRUE
6        2016-03-31     Echo        FALSE
7        2016-03-31     Falcon      FALSE
```

I want the Alpha on 2016-03-31 to be FALSE, since it does not match the word combination of "Alpha" and "Bravo".

The reason for this combination is I am trying to study this particular combination across time. A technique that is fast is preferable, as I foresee myself applying this idea on a large data set.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on your condition, the 3rd and 4th should be TRUE, rigth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
 data %>% 
     group_by(Date) %>% 
     mutate(combiflag=any(grepl("Alpha", Item)) & any(grepl("Bravo", Item)))
```

Or it can be

```
data %>% 
     group_by(Date) %>% 
     mutate(combiflag= if(any(grepl("Alpha", Item)) & any(grepl("Bravo", Item))) 
                            grepl("Alpha|Bravo", Item) else FALSE)
#   Case       Date    Item combiflag
#  <int>      <chr>   <chr>     <lgl>
#1     1 2016-03-25   Alpha      TRUE
#2     2 2016-03-25   Bravo      TRUE
#3     3 2016-03-25 Charlie     FALSE
#4     4 2016-03-25   Delta     FALSE
#5     5 2016-03-31   Alpha     FALSE
#6     6 2016-03-31    Echo     FALSE
#7     7 2016-03-31  Falcon     FALSE
```

Comment: funnily enough, the second one works for me, but not the first... Thanks for the quick response!