# Collapsing Values based on Condition (Not just only using Group By)

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a continuation of the following Question:

[Creating binary identifiers based on condition of word combinations for filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989133/creating-binary-identifiers-based-on-condition-of-word-combinations-for-filter)

I have this data set now

```
Case   Date         Item       combiflag   Duration   
1      2016-03-25   Alpha      TRUE        70         
2      2016-03-25   Bravo      TRUE        210
3      2016-03-25   Charlie    FALSE       210
4      2016-03-25   Delta      FALSE       210
5      2016-03-31   Alpha      FALSE       210
6      2016-03-31   Echo       FALSE       210
7      2016-03-31   Falcon     FALSE       210
```

What I am aiming for is this output

```
Date         Item             Duration   
2016-03-25   Alpha + Bravo    70         
2016-03-25   Charlie          210
2016-03-25   Delta            210
2016-03-31   Alpha            210
2016-03-31   Echo             210
2016-03-31   Falcon           210
```

Two changes have been noted here.. First, only those with combiflag == TRUE has been combined; second, only the minimum of the duration is taken here.

I have tried the following code:

```
focus <- focus %>% group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(Item = ifelse(any(combiflag=="TRUE"), paste(Item, collapse = " + "), Item), 
              duration = ifelse(any(combiflag=="TRUE"), min(Duration), Duration))
```

which gave this:

```
Date         Item             Duration   
2016-03-25   Alpha + Bravo    70         
2016-03-31   Alpha            210
```

and also the following code:

```
focus <- focus %>% group_by(Date, combiflag) %>%
    summarise(Item = paste(Item, collapse = " + "), 
              duration = min(Duration))
```

which gave the following:

```
Date          combiflag    Item                    Duration   
2016-03-25    FALSE        Charlie + Delta         210
2016-03-25    TRUE         Alpha + Bravo           70         
2016-03-31    FALSE        Alpha + Echo + Falcon   210
```

All to no successes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to `nest` the tables so you can change row size in some nested tables without affecting all groups:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(Date, combiflag) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(data = ifelse(combiflag, 
                         map(data, summarise, 
                             Item = paste(Item, collapse = ' + '), 
                             Duration = min(Duration)), 
                         data)) %>% 
    unnest()

## # A tibble: 6 × 5
##         Date combiflag          Item Duration  Case
##       <fctr>     <lgl>         <chr>    <int> <int>
## 1 2016-03-25      TRUE Alpha + Bravo       70    NA
## 2 2016-03-25     FALSE       Charlie      210     3
## 3 2016-03-25     FALSE         Delta      210     4
## 4 2016-03-31     FALSE         Alpha      210     5
## 5 2016-03-31     FALSE          Echo      210     6
## 6 2016-03-31     FALSE        Falcon      210     7
```

Or with a self-join:

```
df %>% filter(combiflag) %>% 
    group_by(Date) %>% 
    summarise(combiflag = unique(combiflag),
              Item = paste(Item, collapse = ' + '), 
              Duration = min(Duration)) %>% 
    bind_rows(df %>% filter(!combiflag))

## # A tibble: 6 × 5
##         Date combiflag          Item Duration  Case
##       <fctr>     <lgl>         <chr>    <int> <int>
## 1 2016-03-25      TRUE Alpha + Bravo       70    NA
## 2 2016-03-25     FALSE       Charlie      210     3
## 3 2016-03-25     FALSE         Delta      210     4
## 4 2016-03-31     FALSE         Alpha      210     5
## 5 2016-03-31     FALSE          Echo      210     6
## 6 2016-03-31     FALSE        Falcon      210     7
```

Comment: @RonakShah Same thing. `filter` is parallel with the first line, which I like.

Comment: Thanks! I only dared try the self-join version because I can understand the implications of using it with bind_rows(). What's the rationale behind the additional `nest` by `tidyverse`?

Comment: `tidyr::nest` puts all the non-grouping columns into a data.frame per row in a list column, so there's one row per group. That lets you `purrr::map` (or just `lapply`) over the column, running full-table functions on each nested data.frame; here it lets you `summarise` if `combiflag`, else do nothing. The advantage of the approach is that you're less likely to accidentally lose or duplicate rows when things get more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Subsetting into 2 groups based on combiflag : i.e. rbind() the dt[where combiflag = FALSE] with the dt[where combiflag is TRUE]

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt) # working on data as a data.table
> rbind(dt[combiflag==T,] %>% group_by(Date) %>% 
                              summarise(Item = paste(Item[combiflag], collapse = ","), 
                                        Duration = min(Duration)), 
         dt[combiflag == FALSE][,`:=`(combiflag = NULL,Case = NULL)])[order(Date)]
#         Date        Item Duration
#1: 2016-03-25 Alpha,Bravo       70
#2: 2016-03-25     Charlie      210
#3: 2016-03-25       Delta      210
#4: 2016-03-31       Alpha      210
#5: 2016-03-31        Echo      210
#6: 2016-03-31      Falcon      210
```

using the `data.table` method :

```
rbind(dt[combiflag == TRUE , .(Item = paste(Item, collapse = "+"), Duration = min(Duration)), by = "Date"],
      dt[combiflag == FALSE, ][,`:=`(combiflag = NULL,Case = NULL)])[order(Date)]
#         Date        Item Duration
#1: 2016-03-25 Alpha+Bravo       70
#2: 2016-03-25     Charlie      210
#3: 2016-03-25       Delta      210
#4: 2016-03-31       Alpha      210
#5: 2016-03-31        Echo      210
#6: 2016-03-31      Falcon      210
```

Comment: thanks! it's a new way looking at the data. however, my bigger scenario is looking at (sorry, didn't mention in the question), let's say, multiple instances of the example data set combined into a huge data frame. Personally, I have never used `data.table` before, so I am not sure if the rbind can work for the whole data frame. While I am imagining a for loop to use with your code here, it can get inefficient when dealing with a huge data set. nvrtheless, thanks!

Comment: you will have a version of `rbind()` for data.table which is much more efficient . I dont think a for loop is reqd though I can't be certain unless what your data is. Do try it once and let me know

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in a compact way with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df1)[(combiflag), c("Item", "Duration") :=
     .(paste(Item , collapse= " + "), min(Duration)), .( Date)],
          by= names(df1)[-1])[, c("Case", "combiflag") := NULL][]
#          Date          Item Duration
#1: 2016-03-25 Alpha + Bravo       70
#2: 2016-03-25       Charlie      210
#3: 2016-03-25         Delta      210
#4: 2016-03-31         Alpha      210
#5: 2016-03-31          Echo      210
#6: 2016-03-31        Falcon      210
```